# How an Apache reverse proxy to other machine with no port forwading?

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

Is apache can bi-directional reverse to other apache that sit in other machine with mobile ip that not allow port forwading?

I want apache that run in mobile act as apache client that open bi-directional to apache reverse proxy server.

exatcly i can use ssh to VPS to port forwading. but it slow down request, and encrypt all my mobile connection.

So Diagram will like this

Apache act as client and server too <-> Apache reverse proxy <- Client Request.

if no module that can do like that, what other software can cheat this way?

Comment: Just a comment, but it seems to me you probably aren't going to find a much better solution than what you already have with SSH, etc.

Comment: i just curious why no one ever or even apache to solve the problem. so everyone can just host website on the go with phone that have share public ip that not allow port forwading. i have problem with ssh way or vpn. it encrypt all connection. my point to use ssh is just borrow the public ip. and the other problem with ssh is my local apache in mobile vurnerable to owner vps server. thats why i want directly apache can act as client and server to do bi-directional to reverse proxy.

Comment: Apache has to receive requests to process them. If port forwarding isn't possible, additional software and additional steps are required because   Apache was never intended to handle much beyond basic web traffic. But I understand your frustration. I have wanted to host publicly accessible servers under mobile IP addresses before and always found the necessary solutions to be less than ideal.